# Closure not working in pyqt app

Tags: python, pyqt, closures

To run the code:

```
apt-get install python3-venv
python3 -m venv venv
. venv/bin/activate
pip install pyqt5
python3 script.py
```

Code to put into script.py:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineCore import QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QScrollArea


class RequestInterceptor(QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor):

    def __init__(self, process_url):
        super().__init__()
        self.process_url = process_url

    def interceptRequest(self, info):
        self.process_url(info.requestUrl().toString())


class DictionaryComponents(QVBoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, url, process_url):
        super().__init__()

        self.url = url
        qurl = QUrl(url)
        self.host = qurl.host()
        self.process_url = process_url

        self.web_view_ui = QWebEngineView()
        self.web_view_ui.load(qurl)

        print('creating interceptor for host: {}'.format(self.host))
        self._request_interceptor = RequestInterceptor(
            lambda o: self.process_url(self.host, o)
        )
        self.web_view_ui.page().profile().setRequestInterceptor(self._request_interceptor)

        self.addWidget(self.web_view_ui)


class MainWindow(QScrollArea):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        main_container = QWidget()
        main_container_layout = QVBoxLayout()

        for url in ['https://www.google.com', 'https://duckduckgo.com/']:
            dictionary = DictionaryComponents(url, print)
            main_container_layout.addLayout(dictionary)

        main_container.setLayout(main_container_layout)

        self.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.setWidget(main_container)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Actual output of script.py:

```
creating interceptor for host: www.google.com
creating interceptor for host: duckduckgo.com
duckduckgo.com https://www.google.com/
duckduckgo.com https://duckduckgo.com/
```

Expected output of script.py:

```
creating interceptor for host: www.google.com
creating interceptor for host: duckduckgo.com
www.google.com https://www.google.com/
duckduckgo.com https://duckduckgo.com/
```

I expect that requests to https://www.google.com/ prints that www.google.com host, not duckduckgo.com

The script will print much more output: requests + qt/ssl errors that are not important.

I'm familiar with problems like:
http://enki-editor.org/2014/08/23/Pyqt_mem_mgmt.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overriding the first interceptor with the second one because according to the Qt documentation:

> The QWebEngineProfile class provides a web engine profile shared by multiple pages.

EDIT as this answer was probably not sufficient: 
You can use `QWebEnginePage(QWebEngineProfile *profile, QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR)` constructor to provide a different than default profile. This way you will have a separate interceptor per page.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help! I did as You said but it still wasn't working. I replaced lines

```
self.web_view_ui = QWebEngineView()
self.web_view_ui.load(qurl)
```

with this:

```py
self.web_view_ui = QWebEngineView()
self.profile = QWebEngineProfile()
self.page = QWebEnginePage(self.profile)
self.web_view_ui.setPage(self.page)
self.web_view_ui.load(qurl)
```

It turned out, that wrong constructor was invoked:

docs: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#public-functions

```
QWebEnginePage(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR)
```

but I wanted

```
QWebEnginePage(QWebEngineProfile *profile, QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR)
```

So changing to

```
self.page = QWebEnginePage(self.profile, None)
```

solved this case.